# base_url for Django with a reverse proxy

Tags: python, django, nginx

I have a Django project which works in Dev. For the prod, I use nginx as a reverse proxy for my internal users.

So the code is deployed on `http://server1.com/project/` and the user can access throught the reverse proxy on `http://project.server2.com/foo/bar`.

The problem is for the `{% url '' %}` and `{% static '' %}` tags. Both generate relative urls, for example :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css" >
```

So the browser tries to load `http://project.server2.com/static/css/style.css`, and not `http://project.server2.com/foo/bar/static/css/style.css`.

What is the solution to generate absolute path with a custom base url please ?

Comment: How is the MEDIA_ROOT and STATIC_ROOT defined for this project?

Comment: MEDIA_ROOT is not defined, STATIC_ROOT is set to os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "assets"). I use collectstatic to generate it. But I think I must change url and static tags to absolute url.

Comment: Please share you nginx configuration file.

Comment: You need to make sure that nginx and your app server pass the `SCRIPT_NAME` to Django.